# If else statement based on database row

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im having a bit of trouble figuring out how to interact with the database in Laravel.

Im writing a small app, and its come to the point where I need to enter, check and return results.

I have followed the docs to setup authentication and now I can have users log in and out.

So what I want to do is store letters.

I have a table called letters.

A user can write as many letters as they want, their user ID is stored in the letters table in the column called userID

When a user clicks on the 'Letters' navigation item, it takes them to the

```
Route::get('letters')..........
```

When it loads the view, if there are no letters in the database I want it to say 'No previous letters' .. if there is some letters in the DB, I just want it to say 'Welcome back'

I cant find how or where to achieve this.

I'm hoping someone can help me out and give me a bit of a hand writing the code as I cant find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in a controller.

```
Route::get('letters', ['uses' => 'LettersController@index']);
```

And then in your letters controller

```
public function index()
{

    // Grab letters for the user. You need to be sure that the user is logged in
    $letters = Letter::forUser(Auth::user())->get();

    $data = [
        'letters' => $letters
    ];

    // You will be able to call $letters->count() in your view
    return View::make('letters.index', $data);
}
```

In your letter Model

```
public function scopeForUser(User $u)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', '=', $u->id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that .. Do i need that in a model or something? ... How does Letter:all() know to interact with the letters database table?

Comment: Just edited my code. You may use a scope in your Letter Model to grab letters for the user. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: @BigJobbies Just added some more clues regarding query scopes.

Comment: Ahhh ok, im kind of getting the picture ... If i want to run that $letters->count if else statement in my view ... Can i just use it or do i have to append something to the View::make line?

Comment: @BigJobbies Just edited my answer to pass `$letters` to the view

Comment: Thank you heaps for that ... I should be able to change that up for all sorts of things :) ... Thanks again

Comment: @BigJobbies Nice! Good luck!

Comment: Hey, sorry about this, but im getting this error - Argument 1 passed to Letters::scopeForUser() must be an instance of User

Comment: @BigJobbies You need to be user that you are logged in otherwise `Auth::user()` will not return a user instance.

Comment: The user is logged in :S

Comment: Should it be User = $u ?